# SQL Server index included columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I need help understanding how to create indexes.  I have a table that looks like this

- Id
- Name
- Age
- Location
- Education,
- PhoneNumber

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE name = 'sam'
```

1. What's the correct way to create an index for this with included columns?
2. What if the query has a order by statement?

   ```
     SELECT * 
       FROM table1 
      WHERE name = 'sam'
   ORDER BY id DESC
   ```
3. What if I have 2 parameters in my where statement?

   ```
     SELECT * 
       FROM table1 
      WHERE name = 'sam'
        AND age > 12
   ```

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to create an index with included columns?  Either via Management Studio/Toad/etc, or SQL ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx)):

```
CREATE INDEX idx_table_1 ON db.table_1 (name) INCLUDE (id)
```

### What if the Query has an `ORDER BY`

The `ORDER BY` can use indexes, if the optimizer sees fit to (determined by table statistics & query).  It's up to you to test if a composite index or an index with `INCLUDE` columns works best by reviewing the query cost.

If `id` is the clustered key (not always the primary key though), I probably wouldn't INCLUDE the column...

### What if I have 2 parameters in my where statement?

Same as above - you need to test what works best for your query.  Might be composite, or include, or separate indexes.

But keep in mind that:

- tweaking for one query won't necessarily benefit every other query
- indexes do slow down INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements, and require maintenance
- You can use the Database Tuning Advisor (DTA) for index recommendations, including when some are redundant

### Recommended reading

I highly recommend reading Kimberly Tripp's "[The Tipping Point](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx)" for a better understanding of index decisions and impacts.

Comment: @JNK: You saying I'm all sizzle and no steak?! :)

Comment: Equal parts, I'm sure!  Even fine steaks get a garnish.

Comment: Thanks. Id is a primary key. What is the function of the included columns? I still don't understand how or when to use them.

Comment: I hate answers that essentially say "it's up to you to figure out what works best."  This is a very specific example and I would think there is only one "best" approach, and would love to see someone explain what it is and more importantly *why* it works better than the alternatives.  

Surely there are some "best practice" design recommendations and patterns that could be shared here, and illustrated with the user's example.  Telling someone "try every conceivable approach and figure out what's best" is not it.

Comment: @BradGagne: "hate" is a strong word.  The reality is that we do not have all the data, and conceivably will not get access.  We don't have the same hardware, server software versions or network connections.  If you read the article I linked to, you'd see from industry experts that the answer is the same -- "it depends".  As much as SO tries to be a resource, the person asking the question has to face that they might have to get their hands dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know which exactly tasks your DB is going to implement and how many records in it, I would suggest that you take a look at the [Index Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx) MSDN article.  It will allow you to decide yourself which indexes to create.

Answer (score 0):

If `ID` is your primary and/or clustered index key, just create an index on `Name, Age`.  This will cover all three queries.

Included fields are best used to retrieve row-level values for columns that are not in the filter list, or to retrieve aggregate values where the sorted field is in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score -1):

If inserts are rare, create as much indexes as You want.

For first query create index for name column.

Id column I think already is primary key...

Create 2nd index with name and age. You can keep only one index: 'name, ag'e and it will not be much slower for 1st query.